# DatagramSocket send method is asynchronous?

Tags: java, network-programming, datagram

What does it mean that DatagramSocket send operation/method is asynchronous?
That it is not waiting for client to receive datagrams?
I suppose that opposite example is TCP communication where we have connection and guaranted delivery of data.

Add:
The exact sentence in question is: "Send operation is asynchronous and reading operation is blocking." 
Relating to send and receive methods of DatagramSocket class.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the javadocs that says this method (or any method of this class) is asynchronous.  When this method returns, the packet has been queued up to send by the OS.

Comment: That's OK, but it doesn't mean it's not asynchronous.

Comment: Actually, it does.  In regard to sending and receiving, they're two separate operations.  You can do multiple sends or multiple receives without having to do the other.  Where did you read that `send` is asynchronous?

Comment: Do you have any source to supply first sentence of your comment?
Than it means that "send method is synchronous". What does that mean? 
That is from slides from my past Java course.

Comment: It means that after the method returns, the packet is sent.  This is the same with the Socket class which handles TCP.  The fact that delivery is guaranteed doesn't have any bearing on whether or not asynchronous operations are occurring.  Methods in general should be assumed to work in a synchronous manner unless stated otherwise.

Comment: As far as I see you are pointing on synchronous and asynchronous methods as in concurrent programming.
This is not in that sense I think. I will put exact sentence from my slide in question.

Comment: I believe what that means is that the send doesn't wait for any confirmation that the packet was received (because that's the way UDP works).  I don't think I'd necessarily call that asynchronous.

Comment: Yes, that's (almost) the same I supposed. No appropriate terminology here made mess in this case I think.